# How do I do bitwise AND of two numbers?

Tags: c, function, bit-manipulation

For example let's say that I want to calculate bitwise the AND function between 124 and 100, how exactly should I do this? Please explain briefly. Thank you.

Comment: @ZhangYuan: SO exists for a reason. You can advise to use a search bar  located on the top right corner, or even better — suggest a duplicate question. "Google it" is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

`int number = 124 & 100`

---

Explanation:

Convert 124 to bitwise format, assuming a 32 bit integer. =

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1100`

Convert 100 to bitwise format, assuming a 32 bit integer. =

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0100`

ANDING bitwise:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1100
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0100
----------------------------------------
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0100
---------------------------------------
```

Which is `100` in decimal! This will be contained in `number` in the above code!

The AND gate truth table is:

```
+-------+---------+
| A | B | A AND B |
+-------+---------+
|0  | 0 |    0    |
|0  | 1 |    0    |
|1  | 0 |    0    |
|1  | 1 |    1    |
+-------+---------+
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IS_SET(a,b) ((((a & (1 << b)) >> b) > 0?1:0))
#define SET(a,b) ((a |= (1 << b)))
#define CLEAR(a,b) ((a &= ~(1 << b)))

int AND(int a, int b)
{
    int i;
    int c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++){
      if(IS_SET(a,i) && IS_SET(b,i)){
        SET(c,i);
      }else{
        CLEAR(c,i);
      }
    }
    return c;
}

int main(int argc,char *Argv[])
{
   int a = 10;
   int b = 30;
   //Basic UNIT test!
   if((a & b) == AND(a,b)){
      printf("Test pass!");
   }else{
      printf("Test fail!");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the bitwise and operator in C `&` like `124 & 100`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `&` operator:

```
int a = 124, b = 100;
int c = a & b;
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `result = a & b`   ...

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have two numbers A & B in decimal form like A = 12 & B = 15,
Write these numbers in binary form like A = 1100 & B = 1111, so we can get 'AND' by just comparing each bit on the same position of the two numbers then if both bits are 1 then it is 1 otherwise it is 0.

For e.g. in the given example first 2 bits are set i.e. 11, therefore, the answer is 1100.

In coding the '&' operator just do the work for us. e.g.

int res = A&B;
cout<<res<<endl;

output: 1100